# PHP: Does echo wait until a function ends before echoing?

Tags: php, ajax, echo

I'm learning PHP and am going through some source code I found.
In it there's an ajax request as follows:

```
$.post("includes/handlers/ajax_search.php", {query:value, userLoggedIn: user}, function(data) {
    //uses 'data' variable
});
```

What I'm unsure about is, the below code is in the called function and would appear to call echo multiple times. Does the called ajax function wait for all echoes to concatenate before actually echoing or does it act like a sort of a stream?

Some clarification would be really appreciated? Thanks.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($usersReturnedQuery)) {
        $user = new User($con, $userLoggedIn);

        if($row['username'] != $userLoggedIn)
            $mutual_friends = $user->getMutualFriends($row['username']) . " friends in common";
        else 
            $mutual_friends == "";

        echo "<div class='resultDisplay'>
                <a href='" . $row['username'] . "' style='color: #1485BD'>
                    <div class='liveSearchProfilePic'>
                        <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] ."'>
                    </div>

                    <div class='liveSearchText'>
                        " . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "
                        <p>" . $row['username'] ."</p>
                        <p id='grey'>" . $mutual_friends ."</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>";

    }
```

Comment: Not up to Ajax or the client at all - the server only sends the response if it is actually done processing the request.

Comment: @luk2302 Would it be sent on each iteration of the while loop. Or does it all concatenate and be sent as one.

Comment: Is the server done processing the request in the middle of the while loop? Obviously not, no.

Comment: PHP uses an output buffer, and so does the web server. Controlling when something will actually be sent to the client is rather difficult. My advice: Don't even try.

Comment: Thanks, your replies are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo outputs lines instantly. However, PHP has a system write buffer. There is [flush() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) to instantly output buffer to the output.

However, be mindful, that flush() only flushes PHP buffer, there might be another buffers between PHP and browser: web server's buffer, for example.